# Calling a method inside an Anonymous ActionListener that throws and exception, without using try/catch

Tags: java, swing

```
public class Test {
public void buildGUI()
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton send = new JButton("Send");
    send.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            send();
            frame.dispose();
        }
    });
    frame.add(send);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

if the method send() throws MyException how would I have that exception migrate its way out of the Swing thread to my class?

What I want to do with the Exception that's generated is have another class that instantiates it catch the exception like so.

```
public class AnotherTest
{
    public AnotherTest()
    {
         Test t = new Test();
         try
         {
             t.buildGUI();
         }
         catch(MyException e)
         {
             //do stuff.
         }
     }
}
```

That's what I want to happen conceptually, however I know that buildGUI will end before actionPerformed is ever called. So, how would I catch the potential exception in actionPerformed in AnotherTest?

Comment: It's already in your class. What exactly do you want to do with that exception? You can't rethrow it from `buildGUI` because `buildGUI` will be complete by time `actionPerformed` gets called.

Comment: @BheshGurung You're correct, that was my mistake in copying.

Comment: I would have the exception be caught and handled within the send method

Answer (score 1):

A class may not thow an exception. Only methods can.

And a class isn't something that can be executed. A method can be executed.

And what executes the action listener method is the Swing event dispatch thread. The only thing you can do if some method throws an exception in a listener is to catch it and display it somehow : by opening an error dialog box, or putting the exception message in a text area, or anything.

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            send();
        }
        catch (MyException e) {
            someTextArea.setText(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

If you in fact want to communicate from the Swing EDT with the main thread, you could use a BlockingQueue, and have the main thread call `take` on the queue and the listener `offer` the exception to the queue.

Any other thread communication mechanism would do. But make sure not to block the EDT, or the whole GUI will freeze.

Answer (score 1):

A class cannot throw an exception, only methods can so the very first line is a mistake. Second thing, you can surround send() with try...catch() block to handle that exception in which you can either take some error recovery action or display an error message or something like that and that would still serve your purpose.

Comment: As you can see in my edit, I want to handle the exception outside of the send() method.

Comment: This answer suggests a way to do it outside the `send()` method. Amn is talking about handling the exception within your anonymous ActionListener.

Comment: I am not too sure whether what Atrus wants is technically possible, I mean there can be indirect hacks I suppose that you can use to get the exception information in a separate class. One such hack could be creating a global 'code'List<Exception>'code' and just keep adding exceptions to it and retrieve them at one place and handle one by one. Otherwise, under the conventional programming, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Well, why just don't do it? And instead make `send()` call some other thread where your logic runs? And if that thread encounters exception, you can handle it there.

There's no way to throw exception across thread boundaries. You can make `send()` pass  info about occurred exception to outer world by setting some outer flag, which is visible to other threads of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Swing isn't Thread safe, then idea to build Swing GUI inside `try - catch - finally` block is more that contraproductive, you have to preparing all us-safe code blocks separatelly

1) I'm starting with very bad way -> your idea must be wrapped into `invokeLater()`, if is there hard and long running `Stream, File I/O, DB Conenction` then to try wrap that into `invokAndWait()`

but you loading these data from some GUI that there exist, you have lots of time for

2) prepare and load data (`Stream, File I/O, DB Conenction`) before you needed them, then to put these Object to the GUI, when you needed (`would be wrapped into invokeLater`)

3) create GUI (`would be wrapped into invokeLater`), show this `Container`, then load data (`Stream, File I/O, DB Conenction`) if with success, then add a show these data in the GUI

3) create GUI (`would be wrapped into invokeLater`), show this `Container`, load data only for one of `JComponents`, if with success, then show this `JComponent`, same for 2nd. and so on ...

for all three options is required to redirect (`Stream, File I/O, DB Conenction`) load these data, value for `JComponent(s)`, to the `Background Task(s)`, you have two correct ways how to do it,

by using

- `Runnable#Thread`
- `SwingWorker`